# Convert ImageSource to BitmapImage - WPF

Tags: wpf, bitmapimage

I'm using a class library that generates a large ImageSource, > 3000x3750 pixels. I would like to convert this ImageSource to BitmapImage so that I can take advantage of DecodePixelWidth or DecodePixelHeight instead of resizing it everytime this image is generated.

I need to display this image for the user first, and most of the users have a screen resolution of 1024x768, I'm binding this ImageSource to an Image control for this, but it can be noticed how "heavy" it is.

How can I do this? Or what is the best solution for this case?

thanks!

Answer (score 23):

Try doing:

```
myBitmapImage = myImageSource as BitmapImage;
```

That works well.

Comment: The reverse of this worked for me, converted from BitmapImage to ImageSource by casting it. Thanks!

Comment: If the cast here fails, it does so silently. so if `myImageSource` can't be casted to `BitmapImage` then `myBitmapImage ` will be `null`, I would instead use `myBitmapImage = (BitmapImage)myImageSource;` as it would at least give me a exception if all hell breaks loose.

Answer (score 7):

The [`BitmapImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx) type inherits [`BitmapSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.aspx) and ultimately [`ImageSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesource.aspx) (both of which are abstract classes). You need to check what the actual type of your object is, i.e. check `object.GetType().Name`. If you're in luck, it may actually be returning a `BitmapSource` object and you will simply need to cast it to that type before being able to use it as such.

Comment: @Hans: Did you use the exact call I specified in my post? It should really return the *actual* type of the object, not the base type (or type of the variable).

Comment: @Noldorin: yes, I did, the documentation also says the return type is ImageSource... thanks

Comment: @Hans: That's quite strange indeed... the only possible reason of which I can think is that the actual type (that implements ImageSource) is private and therefore not exposed. Just to be sure: have you tried casting to any of the types derived from ImageSource. (See MSDN for a list.) Otherwise, maybe you could tell us what library you're using so we can try it for ourselves.