# Why am I getting a runtime error when I try to convert from an ImageSource to a BitmapImage?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image-processing

I am working of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1598918/969613), trying to convert an ImageSource to a BitmapImage. I have an Image control on a WPF canvas, the source of which is a bitmap, and I want to extract the source property of this control into a variable (which will be an ImageSource), and then cast this as a BitmapImage.

My code is below:

```
ImageSource source = MyImage.Source;
BitmapImage image = (BitmapImage) source;
```

It is basically the same code as in the linked answer, but I am getting the following runtime error on the second line (where I am trying to cast):

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrameDecode' to type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage'.

The logical answer I guess is that this simply can't be done, but the answer linked is accepted, has a favorable comment and four upvotes which is frustrating. I am using Visual Studio 2012 with .Net 4.5, I have tried to compile against 4.0, 3.5 and 3.0, and am seeing the same issue.

I have also tried [Ashura](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1093756/ashura)'s suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11115666/969613) and the result is simply null (as in whenever I use the **as** keyword instead of casting the value of the resulting variable is null).

In my XAML, the source property of my Image control is a ***.bmp** file, I am ultimately trying to get this to a WriteableBitmap, but I need to have a BitmapImage to pass into the WriteableBitmap's constructor.

So my question is, what am I doing wrong? How do I convert from an ImageSource to a BitmapImage?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7507946/754438

Comment: Well, it's not and final type may be different according to what you loaded into your source (don't assume a specific type if not absolutely necessary, I see it as an implementation detail). Edit your answer to say what you need to do with it...

Comment: BitmapFrameDecode is inherited from BitmapFrame -> BitmapSource -> ImageSource... BitmapImage is inherited from BitmapSource, so the 2 classes aren't compatible and this explains your error message.

Comment: @JMK Why do you need to convert to BitmapImage? Maybe it would be sufficient to cast to [BitmapSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.aspx), which is a common base class of BitmapImage and BitmapFrame. Which BitmapImage properties do you really need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to the commenters, you helped me understand the problem.

I ended up taking the **Source** property out of my XAML, and set the below in the **Window Loaded** event to ensure that the **Source** property of my image control was indeed a BitmapImage:

```
private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("sample.bmp", UriKind.Relative));
    MyImage.Source = image;
}
```

If you do this in the XAML instead, the Source property ends up being a **BitmapFrameDecode** object by default.