# How to cast a Window's icon to BitmapImage

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bitmapimage, imagesource

I'm trying thx to the help of this thread [Convert ImageSource to BitmapImage - WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920517/convert-imagesource-to-bitmapimage-wpf) to convert my Window's `icon` which is of type `ImageSource` to `BitmapImage` :

```
var bi = _window.Icon as BitmapImage;
```

The problem is that the cast is not happening (bi is null after executing this line) and I'm sure that the `_window.Icon` is not null, can any one tell me why this conversion is not happening ?

**Update :**

Although the Visual Studio documentation says that the Window.Icon is of tyme `ImageSource` but the debugger is saying that it's a `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrameDecode`

When doing :

```
var bi = (BitmapImage) _window.Icon;
```

I get the following exception:

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrameDecode' to type
>   'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage'.

Comment: Why do you need to do this conversion? For most situations it should be sufficient to use the ImageSource directly.

Comment: Re: your edit, there's no contradiction here... ImageSource is an abstract class, so the icon is never actually an instance of ImageSource; BitmapFrameDecode is a subclass of ImageSource, so it's a valid value for the property. However, it's not a subclass of BitmapImage, so the cast fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that the cast is not happening (bi is null after executing this line) and I'm sure that the _window.Icon is not null

It's not null, but it's probably not a `BitmapImage`. The `Window.Icon` is of type `ImageSource`, from which `BitmapImage` is derived. When you set the icon in XAML, the type of the image is typically `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrameDecode`, which is an internal class derived from `BitmapFrame`; so it's not a `BitmapImage`, which is why the cast fails.

---

EDIT: if you just need to convert the icon to a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, you don't need a `BitmapImage`; a `BitmapSource` is enough.

```
var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapSource)_window.Icon));
using (var stream = new MemoryStream()))
{
    encoder.Save(stream);
    stream.Position = 0; // rewind the stream
    var bitmap = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
    var icon = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(bitmap.GetHicon());
}
```

Comment: Perhaps worth to note that there is `BitmapSource` as common base class of BitmapImage and BitmapFrame (and hence BitmapFrameDecode), which has the common bitmap properties like PixelWidth, PixelHeight, DpiX, DpiY, etc.

Comment: @Clemens, good point. Depending on what the OP really needs, it might be enough to cast to BitmapSource.

Comment: @Thomas : Indeed, I updated my post, so can you please show me how I can achieve the conversion properly, the purpose of this is to cast the Icon of the Window to a `System.Drawing.Icon` object, hence I have to pass through : ImageSource -> BitmapImage -> Bitmap than I save the Bitmap as an Icon by doing : Bitmap.Save("Path", ImageFormat.Icon).
If my procedure is wrong please show me how should I proceed, thx.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque : Thanks that absolutely works, but is there a way to do that without saving the `_window.Icon` like in `using (var stream = File.OpenWrite("icon.png")) encoder.Save(stream);` 

I mean is it possible to go programmatically directly from `(BitmapSource)_window.Icon` to `Bitmap` then to `System.Drawing.Icon` without passing by that IO operation

Comment: @AymenDaoudi, of course, you can use a MemoryStream instead of a FileStream, and load the Bitmap from that stream rather than from a file (Image.FromStream)

Comment: @AymenDaoudi, I edited my answer to show how to use a MemoryStream instead

Comment: @AymenDaoudi Just a note. Answering this question would have been a lot easier if you had told us from the start that you wanted to convert to `System.Drawing.Icon`.

Comment: @Clemens Indeed, it's just that I avoided duplicating same other questions.

Answer (score 1):

No idea why exactly you would need to cast to `BitmapImage`. In every practical situation it should be sufficient to cast to `BitmapSource` instead (which is the common base class of `BitmapImage` and `BitmapFrame`):

```
var bitmap = _window.Icon as BitmapSource;
```

`BitmapSource` provides all relevant bitmap properties, like `PixelWidth`, `PixelHeigth`, `DpiX`, `DpiY`, `Format`, etc.