# WPF MVVM Binding Window Icon to a property in view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, window

I have a WPF MVVM application. In my project properties I have set the icon in "Application" tab.

I am trying to unify the way the Window Icon is obtained from different places in my entire application. So I have created an extension method in a class:

```
internal static class IconUtilities
{
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

    public static ImageSource ToImageSource(this Icon icon)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = icon.ToBitmap();
        IntPtr hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();

        ImageSource wpfBitmap = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
            hBitmap,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            Int32Rect.Empty,
            BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

        if (!DeleteObject(hBitmap))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        return wpfBitmap;
    }
}
```

And a public property in my view model:

```
public Icon WindowIcon
{
    get
    {
        return Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    }
}

public ImageSource GetWindowIcon()
{
    return WindowIcon.ToImageSource();
}
```

so wherever I need to obtain the app icon in my view model I call this property to obtain it. So I ensure I am always using the same app icon.

Now, I amb trying to bind this property to the window icon by doing this:

```
<Window x:Name="MainWindow" x:Class="My.Apps.WPF.wMain"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" 
    Icon="{Binding WindowIcon}"
/>
</Window>
```

but in runtime the Window icon shown is the default, not that set in project properties. What am i doing wrong?

**ATTEMPT #1**:

This was being called before InitializeComponents so I have moved into Window Loaded event.

Now, from Window:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Icon = ((wMainViewModel)this.DataContext).WindowIcon;
}
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot convert implicitly 'System.Drawing.Icon' type into 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'
```

So I try to do below:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Icon = ((wMainViewModel)this.DataContext).GetWindowIcon();
}
```

And now I get the error:

```
ImageSource for Icon property should be an icon file.
```

**TESTING APP**:

---

### SIMPLE WPF TESTING APPLICATION (NOT MVVM) - FOR TESTING PURPOSES ONLY

Below I write a complete WPF Application (NOT MVVM), taken from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38291/Implement-Splash-Screen-with-WPF) and added some code. This sample code differs from all above posted: the purpose
of this sample is to show the problem when assigning an ImageSource to a
Window Icon. It has been tested in Visual Studio 2008 with NET Framework 3.5 and Visual Studio 2015 and NET Framework 3.5 as well. Both cases fails in SplashScreen code-behind constructor when setting this.Icon, see later in code below.

Also the icon file (*.ico) used to test is: "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\images\bing.ico". This icon file has been added to my project and I have set build action as resource and not to copy to output directory as its properties.

Also, in project properties, in application tab, I have select this icon (bing.ico) as the icon for the application. This icon will be extracted from code using below line:

System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

See later in my code, just in SplashScreen code-behind, in the constructor.

**Additional notes**: I have Windows 8.1 Pro x64.

**App.cs** :

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace SplashDemo
{
    class App: Application
    {
        [STAThread ( )]
        static void Main ( )
        { 
            Icon ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            Splasher.Splash = new SplashScreen(ico);
            Splasher.ShowSplash();

            for ( int i = 0; i < 5000; i++ )
            {                
                DispatcherHelper.DoEvents();
                Thread.Sleep ( 1 );
            }

            new App ( );
        }

        public App ( )
        {         
            StartupUri = new System.Uri ( "MainWindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative );

            Run ( );            
        }
    }
}
```

**Notes**: Icon object is of type System.Drawing.Icon

**DispatcherHelper Class** :

```
using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace SplashDemo
{
    public static class DispatcherHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Simulate Application.DoEvents function of <see cref=" System.Windows.Forms.Application"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        [SecurityPermissionAttribute ( SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode )]
        public static void DoEvents ( )
        {
            DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame ( );
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke ( DispatcherPriority.Background,
                new DispatcherOperationCallback ( ExitFrames ), frame );

            try
            {
                Dispatcher.PushFrame ( frame );
            }
            catch ( InvalidOperationException )
            {
            }
        }

        private static object ExitFrames ( object frame )
        {
            ( ( DispatcherFrame ) frame ).Continue = false;

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Splasher Class** :

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace SplashDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Helper to show or close given splash window
    /// </summary>
    public static class Splasher
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        private static Window mSplash;

        /// <summary>
        /// Get or set the splash screen window
        /// </summary>
        public static Window Splash
        {
            get
            {
                return mSplash;
            }
            set
            {
                mSplash = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Show splash screen
        /// </summary>
        public static void ShowSplash ( )
        {
            if ( mSplash != null )
            {
                mSplash.Show ( );
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Close splash screen
        /// </summary>
        public static void CloseSplash ( )
        {
            if ( mSplash != null )
            {
                mSplash.Close ( );

                if ( mSplash is IDisposable )
                    ( mSplash as IDisposable ).Dispose ( );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SplashScreen Class (Code-Behind)** :

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace SplashDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for SplashScreen.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class SplashScreen : Window
    {
        public SplashScreen ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public SplashScreen(Icon icon) : this()
        { 
            // BELOW LINE CRASHES
            this.Icon =  System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        }
    }
}
```

**Notes on SplashScreen class**:

- If I use this.Icon =  System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location); it throws below error in compilation time:

> cannot implicitly convert type 'system.drawing.icon' to
>   'system.windows.media.imagesource'

- If I replace this line by this: this.Icon = icon.ToImageSource2();

Then it throws a run-time error (not compilation error), a System.InvalidOperationException:

> ImageSource for Icon property must be an icon file

**SplashScreen View** :

```
<Window 
    x:Class="SplashDemo.SplashScreen"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SplashDemo" 

    Title="SplashScreen" Height="236" Width="414" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None" 
    Background="Orange" BorderBrush="DarkOrange" BorderThickness="3" 
    ShowInTaskbar="False" ResizeMode="NoResize">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>            
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Name="label1" FontSize="48" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="MintCream">
            <Label.BitmapEffect>
                <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowSize="15" />
            </Label.BitmapEffect> Splash screen
        </Label>

        <Label Grid.Row="1" x:Name="CurrentTask" 
               FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" FontSize="18" FontStyle="Italic"  
               Foreground="White" Content="Loading">
            <Label.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Label">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Label.Loaded">
                            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Content" Duration="00:00:00.8" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="Loading"/>
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="Loading."/>
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4" Value="Loading.."/>
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.6" Value="Loading..."/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger.Actions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Label.Style>
        </Label>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow View** :

```
<Window 
    x:Class="SplashDemo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Main window" Height="332" Width="539" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <Label Margin="39,59,21,102" Name="label1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="36">Application window</Label>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow Code-Behind** :

```
using System.Windows;

namespace SplashDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow ( )
        {
            InitializeComponent ( );
        }
    }
}
```

**IconUtilities Class (To convert from System.Drawing.Icon to System.Windows.Media.ImageSource)** :

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace SplashDemo
{
    internal static class IconUtilities
    {
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

        public static ImageSource ToImageSource(this Icon icon)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = icon.ToBitmap();
            IntPtr hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();

            ImageSource wpfBitmap = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                hBitmap,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                Int32Rect.Empty,
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

            if (!DeleteObject(hBitmap))
            {
                throw new Win32Exception();
            }

            return wpfBitmap;
        }

        // Below a simple method without extra objects:
        public static ImageSource ToImageSource2(this Icon icon)
        {
            ImageSource imageSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
                                          icon.Handle,
                                          Int32Rect.Empty,
                                          BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

            return imageSource;
        }
    }
}
```

**Notes here** :

- ImageSource is of type System.Windows.Media.ImageSource
- ToImageSource2 does the same as ToImageSource but without extra objects, see [here](https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/122e2).

Comment: If there is an error then quote the exact error details.

Comment: @AndyG I have corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `ImageSource` for binding, please take a look at the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.icon?view=windowsdesktop-5.0). You can see that the `Window.Icon` property accepts `BitmapFrame` as its input.

Below is the code provided in the official documentation, describing how to set the icon with code.

```
// Set an icon using code
Uri iconUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WPFIcon2.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
this.Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(iconUri);
```

After trying all the other data types with no luck, I can guess it only accepts `BitmapFrame`??? In the code by Microsoft, it uses `BitmapFrame.Create(iconUri);` Also, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875435/how-to-cast-a-windows-icon-to-bitmapimage), and it indicates the debugger recognizes Window Icon as `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrameDecode` but not `ImageSource`.
So, forget about converting to `ImageSource` or `System.Drawing.Icon`, just use `BitmapFrame`. Simply change your `ImageSource` part to below fixes the issue.

In MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
private BitmapFrame _bfWindowIcon;

public BitmapFrame BfWindowIcon
{
    get { 
        return _bfWindowIcon;
    }
    set {
        _bfWindowIcon = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BfWindowIcon));
    }
}

private void VoidUpdateIcon() {
   IconBitmapDecoder ibd = new IconBitmapDecoder(
   new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/Icon_Green.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
   BitmapCreateOptions.None,
   BitmapCacheOption.Default);
   BfWindowIcon = ibd.Frames[0];
}
```

In MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class=
...
...
Icon="{Binding BfWindowIcon}">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewmodels:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
...
...
</Window>
```

---

To bind `Window.Icon` when using `IValueConverter` needs some tricks because the StaticResource in .xaml is behind . Below is how I used this with `IValueConverter`

Converter.cs

```
public class ServiceStateToWindowIconConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            ServiceState val = (ServiceState)value;
            if (val == ServiceState.OK)
            { 
                return BfGetBitmapFrameByURI("pack://application:,,,/ProjectName;component/Resources/Icon_Green.ico");
            }
            else if (val == ServiceState.Warning)
            {
                return BfGetBitmapFrameByURI("pack://application:,,,/ProjectName;component/Resources/Icon_Orange.ico");
            }
            else
            {
                return BfGetBitmapFrameByURI ("pack://application:,,,/ProjectName;component/Resources/Icon_Red.ico");
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private BitmapFrame BfGetBitmapFrameByURI(string strUri)
        {
            IconBitmapDecoder ibd = new IconBitmapDecoder(
            new Uri(strUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
            BitmapCreateOptions.None,
            BitmapCacheOption.Default);
            return ibd.Frames[0];
        }
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window 
xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace"
...
... 
Background="Transparent">
...
    <Window.Resources>
        <Converters:ServiceStateToWindowIconConverter x:Key="ServiceStateToWindowIconConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Icon>
        <Binding Path="ServiceStateForConverter" Converter="{StaticResource ServiceStateToWindowIconConverter}"/>
    </Window.Icon>
...
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Binding

```
<Window ... Icon="{Binding WindowIcon}">
```

requires that the `WindowIcon` property is an `ImageSource`

So you certainly wanted to implement your view model like shown below, which works without any code behind in a Loaded event handler.

```
public ImageSource WindowIcon
{
    get { return GetWindowIcon().ToImageSource(); }
}

public static Icon GetWindowIcon()
{
    return Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
}
```

Comment: Firstly I tried to bind from xmal the window icon to view model property and it does not work, my icon is not shown instead it is shown the default one. Then in attempt #1, I do not bind in xaml the icon to the view model property, instead I set it from Window loaded event and I then get those errors.

Comment: The code in my answer works. I've tested it. Did you assign the Window's DataContext property to an instance of your view model class?

Comment: Yes, I have assigned window's datacontext property to an instance of the view model class but in run-time below error appears (more or less translated from Spanish): The value 'System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression' cannot be assigned to the  'Icon' property of the object 'My.Apps.WPF.wMain'. ImageSource for the Icon property. It must be an icons file.  Error in 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' object in markup file.

Comment: Did you use the method and property *exactly* as shown in this answer, without any of your Loaded event handlers?

Comment: Yes, I am exactly using the 2 methods you have posted in your answer, and I am not using Window Loaded event.

Comment: It's not two methods, but one property and one method. Declared in a `class ViewModel` and assigned to the Window's DataContext by `DataContext = new ViewModel();` in the MainWindow constructor. Works as expected on my side.

Comment: Yes, sorry, one method and one property. Datacontext is initialized as you said in MainWindow constructor and then InitializeComponents is called. I do not know why it is not working. It is saying an icons file is required...

Comment: I get the error: ImageSource for Icon property must be an icon file.

Comment: When you say you have tested and works, have you set icon in project properties with another different from the default? If so, which icon have you used? Maybe it is the icon type, mine is an *.ico and it is not working with the code you posted. I have checked it doing a little program and it does not work. Same error is thrown. Can you attach your example that is working? Which Visual Studio do you use?

Comment: I've set a `.ico` file in the Application tab in the project Properties. Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I am using a .ico file as well in the application tab in project properties but using Visual Studio 2008. I don't think the problem was in Visual Studio.... Also as I have said to you, I have done a simple testing app in Visual Studio 2015 at home, and the same error is thrown. I highly appreciate if you can upload your working example to somewhere so that I can download and compare with mine.

Comment: Sorry, I won't upload anything. It's all in the answer. Works for me with several valid `.ico` files.

Comment: Search your `C:\Program Files` folder. There are plenty.

Comment: In your answer the Icon, what type is it? System.Drawing.Icon?

Comment: There's `Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon`, so it's obviously System.Drawing.Icon. And I pass it to your `ToImageSource` extension method to convert it to ImageSource.

Comment: ok, thanks. in more or less 1-2 hours I will post a complete example here. Not a MVVM, it is only a simple testing WPF application with a splash screen called from a main window so you can see the entire code not working.

Comment: I have posted a complete WPF program (NOT MVVM). Start reading from section: "Testing app - Simple WPF Testing Application (NOT MVVM) - For Testing Purposes only". This code fails when setting This.Icon (Window Icon). I have checked it in Visual Studio 2008 and 2015 and NET Framework 3.5. Both fail.

Comment: Also I have checked that this.Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) is correct in Winforms but not in WPF.

Comment: Obviously `this.Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(...)` won't compile, because ImageSource and Icon are different types. I have no idea why you're still mentioning this fact all the time. It's blatantly obvious, and you should remove that from your sample code. You need to convert from Icon to ImageSource with one of your two conversion methods. I've tested the second one, and it also works for me.

Comment: For me, when trying to convert Icon to ImageSorce with one of the methods posted in IconUtilities class is not working. To discard problems with my icon I have used that in C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe and it is also failing. I do not understand nothing, it is so weird.